# Hide modebar in plotly Dash

Tags: plotly, plotly-dash

In our Dash chart, we're trying to hide the floating toolbar, which allows the user to zoom, pan, save, capture etc.
To achieve that I know that in plotly you can set the *displayModeBar* param to false.
How can this be done in Dash?

Comment: Any luck so far? It looks like this forum is highly responsive : https://community.plot.ly/c/dash

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The Dash Core has been updated and it now offer a cleaner solution.
A specific config parameter with a value `'displayModeBar': False` has been introduced

From [Plotly forum](https://community.plot.ly/t/is-it-possible-to-hide-the-floating-toolbar/4911/6)

```
dcc.Graph(
    id='my-graph',
    figure={'data': [{'x': [1, 2, 3]}]},
    config={
        'displayModeBar': False
    }
)
```

The config parameter let you even to hide and remove specific buttons.

For example:

```
config={
        'modeBarButtonsToRemove': ['pan2d', 'lasso2d']
    }
```

Note that to make it work you have to update all Dash components.

In my configuration (`pip` and `virtualenv`) the following commands were necessary:

```
pip install dash --upgrade
pip install dash-core-components --upgrade
pip install dash-html-components --upgrade
pip install dash-renderer --upgrade
```

Answer (score 1):

Indeed the forum helped solved this issue.
For completeness I'm posting the answer here:

Create a my.css file under the static folder in Flask, with:

```
.modebar { display: none !important; }
```

And then:

```
my_css_url = "/static/my.css"  
app.css.append_css(
    { “external_url”: my_css_url }
)
```